# Form submit in $(document).ready(function(){. Is there a simple fix?

Tags: form-submit, document-ready

This should be an easy fix for the right guru!  Everything is working for me except that I can't get this form to submit without clicking the submit button. The data values are all valid.  The action page, ...gdform.php, uses $_post to get the "redirect" value from the form and then uses php to do a  header Location change.  That works fine if I execute the form with the submit button. I just need it to happen without any click...
Take a look, please!

```
<?php session_start();
require_once('Connect.php') ;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>Nitrofill Document</title>

<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
$sn=$_GET['num'];
echo $sn;

mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR die('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
mysql_select_db($dbname);
 $selectSQL = "select * from `Presentations` where `serialnum` ='" . $sn ."'" ;

$result = mysql_query($selectSQL) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,  MYSQL_BOTH);
$thedoc = urldecode($row['docurl']);
$therecip=urldecode($row['recipient']);
$thetracker=urldecode($row['tracker']);
$lastacc=urldecode($row['last_accessed']);

?>
</head>
<body>

<form id="notice" action="http://m3sglobal.com/gdform.php" method="post"> 
<input  name="subject" value="<?php echo $therecip . " has viewed the document you sent them.";?> " /> 
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo $thedoc ; ?>"/>
<label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $thetracker ; ?>"/>
<label>Comments:</label><textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="5">
Document Viewed:<?php echo $thedoc ; ?>

When Accessed:<?php echo $lastacc ; ?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
   myfunc
 });

function myfunc () {
var frm = document.getElementById("notice");
frm.submit();
}

</script>
```

Comment: "This should be an easy fix for the right guru!" my favorite headline on the $4 jobs at vworker.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but shouldn't it be: (corrected typos)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   myfunc(); <--// with ();
}); 

function myfunc() {  <--// without space
    var frm = document.getElementById("notice");
    frm.submit();
}
```

or better yet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("form#notice").submit();
});
```

**EDIT:**

Prowla is right, you also didn't declare the jQuery library. Good catch Prowla, I missed that, just saw the typos.

**EDIT #2:**

Your code is pretty messy there, and you have that PHP generated string in the `<head>`. Also your submit had no `value`, you used `name`.  I cleaned it up, here is working code (for me at least):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Nitrofill Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form#notice").submit();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!--// ALL THE PHP SHOULD GO HERE TO MAKE THE URL BELOW //-->
qyO452ZKphttps://docs.google.com/presentation/pub?id=1chxqg-qjrfEvAR9_Jia7lt4ps2_Q7IfTiI41bQE7Q_4&start=true&loop=false&delayms=3000<br/>greg.mcgee@gmail.com<br/>greg.mcgee@advetel.com<br/>Thu, 23 Feb 2012 19:42:11 MST<br/>
<!--// END PHP //-->

<form id="notice" action="http://m3sglobal.com/gdform.php" method="post"> 
    <input name="subject" value="greg.mcgee@gmail.com has viewed the document you sent them. " /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://docs.google.com/presentation/pub?id=1chxqg-qjrfEvAR9_Jia7lt4ps2_Q7IfTiI41bQE7Q_4&start=true&loop=false&delayms=3000"/>
    <label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" value="greg.mcgee@advetel.com"/>
    <label>Comments:</label><textarea name="comments" cols="40" rows="5">
        Document Viewed:https://docs.google.com/presentation/pub?id=1chxqg-qjrfEvAR9_Jia7lt4ps2_Q7IfTiI41bQE7Q_4&start=true&loop=false&delayms=3000
        When Accessed:Thu, 23 Feb 2012 19:42:11 MST
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You might want to consider using [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to help you troubleshoot your pages. Its how I figured this out. Also remember Prowla's advice, and protect your SQL.

Comment: Still doesn't go.  Here's the link so you can try it yourself:   http://Nitrofill.biz/tr/Nitrofill_Presentation.php?num=qyO452ZKp

Comment: @I_miss_Steve_already - I updated the answer with the correct code

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.  Btw, that code in the header is for testing/confirmation, I know its not cool to leave it in for production.

Comment: @ProwlaIt works only as an html page, with the values already plugged in from the database,  But, if I run it as a php page, it fails.  So, there is something I'll have to do differently because I'm getting the values for the form from a database and then submitting the form, which updates the page.  Just can't figure what that is....

Comment: @Prowla  In Firebug, I get this notice:"Use of getAttributeNodeNS() is deprecated. Use getAttributeNS() instead.", and this error:  e[h] is not a function, line 3.  This is in the jQuery script.  The value of h is "submit".  I see this but I don't know what to do about it....

Comment: @I_miss_Steve_already -  hmmm.. You changed the `name` on the submit to `value` right? That was the "e[h] is not a function" error. If the page is still putting the values out like before that should work. The script only sees the html anyway, I just copied what the page rendered as. I just tried the link you gave earlier and it works fine? Did you sort it out?

Comment: Aha!  I had the name AND the value set to "submit", and this apparently was causing it not to fire.  I changed that, and it worked! Just had to hide all the form pieces and put up a black background.  Finally, the solution!  Thanks for hanging in there with me on this one!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery: (Remember to put the jquery script in your `<head>` tags).

```
 <head>
 ...
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 ...
 <head>
 ...
 // submit form with id notice
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#notice').submit();
 });
```

Also your SQL is subject to injection. Please look into using prepared statements.
Sample in PHP:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select * from `Presentations` where `serialnum` =?');
$stmt->bind_param('i',$sn);
$stmt->execute();
....
```

Comment: When I get the other part working, I'll try this.  I haven't been using mysqli, or prepared statements, but I guess its time.  This looks like a simpler solution to the "injection" problem than others I've seen.  One thing I don't understand in the code above:  in the statement it looks like the variable is "?", but then you're binding it to 'i' on the next line.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct (assuming your serial number is an integer). The ? is a placeholder that you need to bind a variable to. The `i` stands for a variable of type integer. So I am binding an integer, the value in $sn to the first ? in the query. (i - int, d - double, s - string and b - blob). Sample:
`$stmt->bind_param('idsb',$int,$double,$string,$blob);`